# ¿Cómo crear una función para imprimir una factura a partir de la información suministrada por datos quemados?

Tags: python, poo

Factura:
Se solicita crear una función que tome como insumo los objetos creados y genere
una factura, teniendo en consideración lo siguiente:
Para calcular el monto del consumo por mes, los proveedores de agua potable,
miden el consumo en metros cúbicos

```
import random
class abonado:
    def __init__(self):
        self.identificador=""
        self.nombre=""
        self.direccion=""
        self.telefono=0
        self.medidor=0
        self.acumulado=0
        return
    def setIdentificador(self,i):
        self.identificador=i
        return
    def setNombre(self,n):
        self.nombre=n
        return
    def setDireccion(self,d):
        self.direccion=d
        return
    def setTelefono(self,t):
        self.telefono=t
        return
    def setMedidor(self,m):
        self.medidor=m
        return
    def setAcumulado(self,a):
        self.acumulado=a
        return
    def getIdentificador(self):
        return self.identificador
        
    def getNombre(self):
        return self.nombre
        
    def getDireccion(self):
        return self.direccion
        
    def getTelefono(self):
        return self.telefono
        
    def getMedidor(self):
        return self.medidor
        
    def getAcumulado(self):
        return self.acumulado
#************
class consumo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.identificador=""
        self.medidor=0
        self.mes=0
        self.metros=0
        return
    def setIdentificador(self,i):
        self.identificador=i
        return
    def setMedidor(self,m):
        self.medidor=m
        return
    def setMes(self,m):
        self.mes=m
        return
    def setMetros(self,m):
        self.metros=m
        return
    def getIdentificador(self):
        return self.identificador
    def getMedidor(self):
        return self.medidor
    def getMes(self):
        return self.mes
    def getMetros(self):
        return self.metros
        
   
        
    

def Bdabonados():
    abonados= [{"204340221": ["Hilda Araya", "Palmira, Zarcero", 87780717, 1, 527 ] },
               {"204340333": ["Ana Araya", "La Brisa, Zarcero", 87782583, 2, 652 ]},
               {"201470999": ["Ronny Durán", "La Palmita, Zarcero", 60625489, 3, 836]},
               {"101110111": ["Roberh Lopez", "Palmira, Zarcero", 60625489, 4, 0]},
               {"102220222": ["Aylin Cespedez", "Tapezco, Zarcero", 60625489, 5, 0]},
               {"103330666": ["Michelle Jimenez", "Santa Rosa, Zarcero", 60625489, 6, 0]},
               {"201590487": ["Pablo Carranza", "Los Angeles, Zarcero", 60625489, 7, 0]}]
    return abonados
def CreaAbonados(La):
    ABONADOS=[]
    for abonados in La:
        for abo in abonados:
            objeto=abonado()
            objeto.setIdentificador(abo)
            objeto.setNombre(abonados[abo][0])
            objeto.setDireccion(abonados[abo][1])
            objeto.setTelefono(abonados[abo][2])
            objeto.setMedidor(abonados[abo][3])
            objeto.setAcumulado(abonados[abo][4])
            ABONADOS.append(objeto)
        
    
    print(ABONADOS)
    return ABONADOS
def CreaConsumos(La):
    CONSUMOS=[]
    ident=1
    for i in range (len (La)):
        
        
        for j in range (1,13,1):
            
            objeto=consumo()
            objeto.setMedidor(La[i].getMedidor())
            
            objeto.setIdentificador(ident)
            
            
            objeto.setMes(j)
            objeto.setMetros(random.randint(10,600))
            CONSUMOS.append(objeto)
            
            ident=ident+1

        
    return CONSUMOS

    

def main():
    Abo=Bdabonados()
    La=CreaAbonados(Abo)
    Lc=CreaConsumos(La)

    print(Lc.CONSUMOS)

    CreaAbonados()
    
        
    return
main()
```

El objetivo del programa es crear una función que a partir de dicho código, se pueda crear una función para imprimir una factura para cada uno de los abonados, de tal manera que se regrese la información en la consola. La duda mía es cómo crear esa función sin utilizar métodos de Python en sus bibliotecas, es decir, completamente manual

Comment: Sin usar métodos de python... por ejemplo?

Comment: ¡Gracias! No lo había pensado ;)